# How to check if entries in table in postgres are increasing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a table temp(a int). It has values some values stored in it. How can I know if all those values are strictly increasing or not?

For example, temp may contain 1,2,3- values in strictly increasing sequence or 1,1,2- not strictly increasing. Thanks!

Comment: can you please add what you already tried and what challeges are you facing ? That would help you to get your query resolved quickly.

Answer (score 5):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, if your table has only one column, there is no answer -- the question has no meaning because there is no ordering.

If I assuming you have an ordering column, you can simply use `lag()`.  For a flag on the table, here is logic:

```
select (count(*) > 0) as not_all_increasing
from (select t.*, lag(val) over (order by <orderingcol>) as prev_val
      from t
     ) t
where prev_val > val;
```

Just use `select t.*` if you want to see the values that are non-increasing.